# How to handle KeyError: "['blah'] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking at the US names dataset (SSA), as described in Python for Data Analysis by Wes McKinney.

This **works**:

```
total_births = top1000.pivot_table('births', index = 'year', columns = 'name', aggfunc = sum)
subset = total_births[['Michael', 'Mike', 'Martin']].fillna(0)
subset.plot( title = 'Number of births per year', grid = True, figsize=(28,20), xticks=range(1880, 2020, 5)).get_figure().savefig('output2.png', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

But when I add an unpopular name, which nevertheless is in the data set:

```
subset = total_births[['Michael', 'Mike', 'Martin', 'Ammar']].fillna(0)
```

...I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "names.py", line 44, in <module>
    subset = total_births[['Michael', 'Mike', 'Martin', 'Ammar']].fillna(0)
  File "/home/mike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1774, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/home/mike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1818, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "/home/mike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1143, in _convert_to_indexer
    raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['Ammar'] not in index"
```

I tried adding fillna(0), but it doesn't help... The code is available at https://github.com/m1key/data-science-sandbox (ade55154f177410e1e269d64766a4e8b8e1ae585), the troublesome lines are commented out.

Sample data set:

```
name  Aaden  Aaliyah  Aanya  Aarav  Aaron  Aarush  Ab  Abagail  Abb  Abbey  \
year                                                                         
1880    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN    102     NaN NaN      NaN  NaN    NaN   
1881    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN     94     NaN NaN      NaN  NaN    NaN   
1882    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN     85     NaN NaN      NaN  NaN    NaN   
1883    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN    105     NaN NaN      NaN  NaN    NaN   
1884    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN     97     NaN NaN      NaN  NaN    NaN   

name  ...   Zoa  Zoe  Zoey  Zoie  Zola  Zollie  Zona  Zora  Zula  Zuri  
year  ...                                                               
1880  ...     8   23   NaN   NaN     7     NaN     8    28    27   NaN  
1881  ...   NaN   22   NaN   NaN    10     NaN     9    21    27   NaN  
1882  ...     8   25   NaN   NaN     9     NaN    17    32    21   NaN  
1883  ...   NaN   23   NaN   NaN    10     NaN    11    35    25   NaN  
1884  ...    13   31   NaN   NaN    14       6     8    58    27   NaN
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Any reason you don't just check first and remove the name? You can just define a list of names of interest and then remove the ones that are not in the index and pass those

Comment: I mean, I want that name to show in the graph, as there is some data for it, just not for every year.

Comment: Ammar is not in that sample dataset.

Are you absolutely certain "Ammar" exists in your total_births? try `'Ammar' in total_births.columns` and let us know if True or False

Comment: Sorry, that's false, as I am looking at the restricted top 1000 data set... I will need to figure out how to look at the entire data set. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Ammar doesn't appear to be in your dataset.

In order to double check, try `'Ammar' in total_births.columns` which will return a boolean (`True` or `False`)